# LaTeX one column title and index in a two column document

Tags: latex

I'm trying to write a document using the twocolumn option but I found that the title and the index are formatted in the same way as the text. How can I have a twocolumn document with the title and the index onecolumn?
I've tried @twocolumn false and the abstrack package but the first gives me a one column half page long and the second do not allow me to span the index fr multiple pages.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}   

\twocolumn[  
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \begin{center}

             ...complicated research title here....

         \end{center}
     \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
```

Comment: Magic! Thank you